How to determine which x86 memory operand width and type is used from an asm listing?
There are several versions of the same instruction: IDIV M32, IDIV R32, IDIV M64, IDIV R64 (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/idiv)
How to understand which one is used? Let's say
vdiv(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&):
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rcx+4]
        cdq
        idiv    DWORD PTR [rcx+8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx], eax
        ret

Is it 32 bit since it uses int? Is it 64 bit since it uses 64 bit rcx register? Probably 32 bit, but is it M or R? How to spot the difference between those (M/R) two?

It is the M32 because the operand is 32 bits in memory (a dword). rcx is the address, that is not relevant.

The address-size attribute of idiv dword ptr [rcx+8] is 64-bit (RCX in the addressing mode).  The operand-size is 32-bit (width of data loaded from memory, specified by dword ptr.  Without that it would be ambiguous, unlike mov rcx, [rdi] where the destination register implies the operand size (64-bit) even if qword ptr hadn't been used.  You can tell the operand is memory because there are square brackets and it uses ptr (in GAS's .intel_syntax noprefix mode which is like MASM)

Does it mean that direct call to the register rcx without dword ptr will be R? idiv rcx = R64, idiv eax = R32?

Yes, that is correct.

Yes, but note that idiv eax is a bad example: you basically never want to divide EDX:EAX by EAX.  Actually that's somewhat interesting: for positive EAX and EDX and assuming EAX > EDX so it doesn't #DE fault with an overflow, the remainder of ((EDX<<32) + EAX) % EAX is (EDX<<32) % EAX, because the EAX % EAX part is 0.  (And its contribution to the quotient is 1).

'R' is 'Register , like ah/al/ax/eax/bx/cx/dx...etc.
'M' is 'Memory' , a Address of your Memory
R8 = 8 Bits Register, like ah/al/bh/bl/ch/cl/dh/dl/...
R16 = 16 bits one, ax/bx/cx/dx/si/di/bp/sp/...
R32 = 32 bits, EAX, ECX, EDX, EBX, ESP, EBP, ESI, EDI,...
R64 = RAX, RBX, RCX, RDX, RDI, RSI, RBP, RSP, R8~R15
M8 = 8 Bits(1Byte) memory, byte ptr [si] , byte ptr [edx] , mov byte ptr [rdx], 255
M16 = 16 bits(1Word), word ptr [rdx], word ptr [esi], mov WORD ptr [di], 65535
M32 = 32 bits(1Dword - Double Word), DWord ptr [si], mov DWORD ptr [bx], 10
M64 = 64 bits(1qword), QWord ptr [] ...
so, the idiv DWORD PTR [xxx] is  M32
idiv QWORD PTR [xxx] is  M64
...

idiv RDi=R64, idiv EDi=R32, idiv Di=R16, idiv dh=R8

mov WORD ptr [dh], imm16 is impossible: address-size of 8-bit is not encodeable in any mode.  Only 32 or 64-bit address-size are possible in 64-bit mode.  16 or 32 in other modes.  Same for a [dl] addressing mode.  The 16-bit registers you picked can be used in 16-bit addressing modes, so those are fine, and 32/64-bit addressing modes allow any register as the base.  And you didn't explicitly write qword ptr [bx] or something, which would also be impossible because 64-bit operand-size means you're in 64-bit mode so no 16-bit address-size.

Also, for 8-bit registers you left out sil / dil / bpl / spl / r8b / r9b / ...  (all of those only available in 64-bit mode, which the OP is using.)

@PeterCordes yeap, as you mentioned, these are ONLY in 64-bits mode. So, I really don't want to introduce these. To avoid they confused in NOT 64-bits environment.

If I introduce, r8b / r9b ...etc. I might need to introduce r8w, r9w,.. and r14d, r15d...etc. That's a little too complicated for a new one, is't it.

@PeterCordes yes, you are right, For the mov command, mov M8,imm does not exist. That's my fault.

mov byte ptr [rdx], 255 is mov M8, imm.  The M8 is indicating the operand-size, not the address-size.  You very rarely want to use an address-size that's not the default for the mode, but it's common to use different operand sizes.  As for not mentioning dil and r8w etc., yeah you did say "like", implying that it's not an exhaustive list.  You could shorten it to just AH / AL, maybe, to make it more clear that it's not exhaustive, since it's weird to list all the legacy 8-bit regs and none of the "new" 64-bit-mode ones.

@PeterCordes Because I don't understand his working environment. If he knew there was a register named sil, but they are building their code under 32 bits environment, that may cause confusion for them for a long time. So, that's why I say I don't want to do this. Please understand. And more dot notation has been added, thanks for mentioning it.

You can see from the asm in the question that it's 64-bit because it uses 64-bit registers like RDX which are only accessible in 64-bit mode.  That's why I added the [x86-64] tag.  But sure, other future readers with the same question about 32-bit code could benefit from your answer so it's fine.  This answer doesn't need to teach people which registers  exist, that's a separate question which is pretty fundamental and well-explained in many  guides and tutorials.
